# How to set the image size for an ImageView with rounded corners

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I've added an `ImageView` with rounded corners to a `ListView`. My project is working fine. But not all the images are the same size. My code is below:

```
holder.img.setImageBitmap(createRoundedBitmap(user.getbi(),20));


private Bitmap createRoundedBitmap(Bitmap getbi, int i) {
 if (getbi == null) {
        return null;
    }    
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, getbi.getWidth(), getbi.getHeight());

    // create output bitmap

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(getbi.getWidth(), getbi.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    // assign canvas with output bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    canvas.drawARGB(0,0, 0,0);

    // initialize paint
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    // draw rounded rect to bitmap
    paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(rect), i, i, paint);

    // copy original bitmap to rounded area
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(getbi, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

So, what should I do to fix the size of this bitmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
private Bitmap createRoundedBitmap(Bitmap getbi, int i,int neededWidth,int neededHeight) {
 if (getbi == null) {
        return null;
    }    
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, neededWidth, neededHeight);
    Rect bmRect = new Rect(0, 0, getbi.getWidth(), getbi.getHeight());
    // create output bitmap

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(neededWidth, neededHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);

    // assign canvas with output bitmap
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    canvas.drawARGB(0,0, 0,0);

    // initialize paint
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    // draw rounded rect to bitmap
    paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(rect), i, i, paint);

    // copy original bitmap to rounded area
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(getbi, bmRect , rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

**Usage :**

> createRoundedBitmap(yourBitmap,5,100,100); // You will get a bitmap 100x100 px

Comment: its work. but my image is crop. so how can i get full image in that??

Comment: works fine. bit image is not properly shown. like clarity down.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**RoundedImageView.java**

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

  public static final String TAG = "RoundedImageView";
  public static final int DEFAULT_RADIUS = 0;
  public static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
  private static final ScaleType[] SCALE_TYPES = {
      ScaleType.MATRIX,
      ScaleType.FIT_XY,
      ScaleType.FIT_START,
      ScaleType.FIT_CENTER,
      ScaleType.FIT_END,
      ScaleType.CENTER,
      ScaleType.CENTER_CROP,
      ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE
  };

  private int mCornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
  private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
  private ColorStateList mBorderColor =
      ColorStateList.valueOf(RoundedDrawable.DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
  private boolean mOval = false;
  private boolean mRoundBackground = false;

  private int mResource;
  private Drawable mDrawable;
  private Drawable mBackgroundDrawable;

  private ScaleType mScaleType;

  public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
  }

  public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedImageView, defStyle, 0);


    int index = a.getInt(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_android_scaleType, 1);
    if (index >= 0) {
      setScaleType(SCALE_TYPES[index]);
    } else {
      // default scaletype to FIT_CENTER
      setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    }

    mCornerRadius = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_corner_radius, 360);
    mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_border_width,2);

    // don't allow negative values for radius and border
    if (mCornerRadius < 0) {
      mCornerRadius = DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    }
    if (mBorderWidth < 0) {
      mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
    }

    mBorderColor = a.getColorStateList(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_border_color);
    if (mBorderColor == null) {
      mBorderColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(R.color.blue);
    }

    mRoundBackground = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_round_background, false);
    mOval = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.RoundedImageView_is_oval, false);

    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();

    a.recycle();
  }

  @Override
  protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    invalidate();
  }

  /**
   * Return the current scale type in use by this ImageView.
   *
   * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ImageView_scaleType
   * @see android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType
   */
  @Override
  public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return mScaleType;
  }

  /**
   * Controls how the image should be resized or moved to match the size
   * of this ImageView.
   *
   * @param scaleType The desired scaling mode.
   * @attr ref android.R.styleable#ImageView_scaleType
   */
  @Override
  public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    if (scaleType == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    if (mScaleType != scaleType) {
      mScaleType = scaleType;

      switch (scaleType) {
        case CENTER:
        case CENTER_CROP:
        case CENTER_INSIDE:
        case FIT_CENTER:
        case FIT_START:
        case FIT_END:
        case FIT_XY:
          super.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
          break;
        default:
          super.setScaleType(scaleType);
          break;
      }

      updateDrawableAttrs();
      updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
      invalidate();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mResource = 0;
    mDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(drawable);
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
  }

  @Override
  public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    mResource = 0;
    mDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromBitmap(bm);
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
  }

  @Override
  public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    if (mResource != resId) {
      mResource = resId;
      mDrawable = resolveResource();
      updateDrawableAttrs();
      super.setImageDrawable(mDrawable);
    }
  }

  @Override public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setImageURI(uri);
    setImageDrawable(getDrawable());
  }

  private Drawable resolveResource() {
    Resources rsrc = getResources();
    if (rsrc == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Drawable d = null;

    if (mResource != 0) {
      try {
        d = rsrc.getDrawable(mResource);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to find resource: " + mResource, e);
        // Don't try again.
        mResource = 0;
      }
    }
    return RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(d);
  }

  @Override
  public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(background);
  }

  private void updateDrawableAttrs() {
    updateAttrs(mDrawable, false);
  }

  private void updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs() {
    updateAttrs(mBackgroundDrawable, true);
  }

  private void updateAttrs(Drawable drawable, boolean background) {
    if (drawable == null) {
      return;
    }

    if (drawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
      ((RoundedDrawable) drawable)
          .setScaleType(mScaleType)
          .setCornerRadius(background && !mRoundBackground ? 0 : mCornerRadius)
          .setBorderWidth(background && !mRoundBackground ? 0 : mBorderWidth)
          .setBorderColors(mBorderColor)
          .setOval(mOval);
    } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
      // loop through layers to and set drawable attrs
      LayerDrawable ld = ((LayerDrawable) drawable);
      int layers = ld.getNumberOfLayers();
      for (int i = 0; i < layers; i++) {
        updateAttrs(ld.getDrawable(i), background);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  @Deprecated
  public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
    mBackgroundDrawable = RoundedDrawable.fromDrawable(background);
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    super.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
  }

  public int getCornerRadius() {
    return mCornerRadius;
  }

  public void setCornerRadius(int radius) {
    if (mCornerRadius == radius) {
      return;
    }

    mCornerRadius = radius;
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
  }

  public int getBorderWidth() {
    return mBorderWidth;
  }

  public void setBorderWidth(int width) {
    if (mBorderWidth == width) {
      return;
    }

    mBorderWidth = width;
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    invalidate();
  }

  public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor.getDefaultColor();
  }

  public void setBorderColor(int color) {
    setBorderColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
  }

  public ColorStateList getBorderColors() {
    return mBorderColor;
  }

  public void setBorderColors(ColorStateList colors) {
    if (mBorderColor.equals(colors)) {
      return;
    }

    mBorderColor =
        (colors != null) ? colors : ColorStateList.valueOf(RoundedDrawable.DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
      invalidate();
    }
  }

  public boolean isOval() {
    return mOval;
  }

  public void setOval(boolean oval) {
    mOval = oval;
    updateDrawableAttrs();
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    invalidate();
  }

  public boolean isRoundBackground() {
    return mRoundBackground;
  }

  public void setRoundBackground(boolean roundBackground) {
    if (mRoundBackground == roundBackground) {
      return;
    }

    mRoundBackground = roundBackground;
    updateBackgroundDrawableAttrs();
    invalidate();
  }
}
```

**RoundedDrawable.java**

```
public class RoundedDrawable extends Drawable {

  public static final String TAG = "RoundedDrawable";
  public static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

  private final RectF mBounds = new RectF();
  private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
  private final RectF mBitmapRect = new RectF();
  private final BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
  private final Paint mBitmapPaint;
  private final int mBitmapWidth;
  private final int mBitmapHeight;
  private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();
  private final Paint mBorderPaint;
  private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();

  private float mCornerRadius = 0;
  private boolean mOval = false;
  private float mBorderWidth = 0;
  private ColorStateList mBorderColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
  private ScaleType mScaleType = ScaleType.FIT_CENTER;

  public RoundedDrawable(Bitmap bitmap) {

    mBitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    mBitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    mBitmapRect.set(0, 0, mBitmapWidth, mBitmapHeight);

    mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);

    mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
    mBitmapPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

    mBorderPaint = new Paint();
    mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor.getColorForState(getState(), DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR));
    mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);
  }

  public static RoundedDrawable fromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
      return new RoundedDrawable(bitmap);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static Drawable fromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable != null) {
      if (drawable instanceof RoundedDrawable) {
        // just return if it's already a RoundedDrawable
        return drawable;
      } else if (drawable instanceof LayerDrawable) {
        LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) drawable;
        int num = ld.getNumberOfLayers();

        // loop through layers to and change to RoundedDrawables if possible
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
          Drawable d = ld.getDrawable(i);
          ld.setDrawableByLayerId(ld.getId(i), fromDrawable(d));
        }
        return ld;
      }

      // try to get a bitmap from the drawable and
      Bitmap bm = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
      if (bm != null) {
        return new RoundedDrawable(bm);
      } else {
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create bitmap from drawable!");
      }
    }
    return drawable;
  }

  public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
      return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap;
    int width = Math.max(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 1);
    int height = Math.max(drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), 1);
    try {
      bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
      Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
      drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
      drawable.draw(canvas);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      bitmap = null;
    }

    return bitmap;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isStateful() {
    return mBorderColor.isStateful();
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean onStateChange(int[] state) {
    int newColor = mBorderColor.getColorForState(state, 0);
    if (mBorderPaint.getColor() != newColor) {
      mBorderPaint.setColor(newColor);
      return true;
    } else {
      return super.onStateChange(state);
    }
  }

  private void updateShaderMatrix() {
    float scale;
    float dx;
    float dy;

    switch (mScaleType) {
      case CENTER:
        mBorderRect.set(mBounds);
        mBorderRect.inset((mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderWidth) / 2);

        mShaderMatrix.set(null);
        mShaderMatrix.setTranslate((int) ((mBorderRect.width() - mBitmapWidth) * 0.5f + 0.5f),
            (int) ((mBorderRect.height() - mBitmapHeight) * 0.5f + 0.5f));
        break;

      case CENTER_CROP:
        mBorderRect.set(mBounds);
        mBorderRect.inset((mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderWidth) / 2);

        mShaderMatrix.set(null);

        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;

        if (mBitmapWidth * mBorderRect.height() > mBorderRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
          scale = mBorderRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
          dx = (mBorderRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
        } else {
          scale = mBorderRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
          dy = (mBorderRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
        }

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth,
            (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth);
        break;

      case CENTER_INSIDE:
        mShaderMatrix.set(null);

        if (mBitmapWidth <= mBounds.width() && mBitmapHeight <= mBounds.height()) {
          scale = 1.0f;
        } else {
          scale = Math.min(mBounds.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth,
              mBounds.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight);
        }

        dx = (int) ((mBounds.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f + 0.5f);
        dy = (int) ((mBounds.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f + 0.5f);

        mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        mShaderMatrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

        mBorderRect.set(mBitmapRect);
        mShaderMatrix.mapRect(mBorderRect);
        mBorderRect.inset((mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderWidth) / 2);
        mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBorderRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        break;

      default:
      case FIT_CENTER:
        mBorderRect.set(mBitmapRect);
        mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
        mShaderMatrix.mapRect(mBorderRect);
        mBorderRect.inset((mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderWidth) / 2);
        mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBorderRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        break;

      case FIT_END:
        mBorderRect.set(mBitmapRect);
        mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.END);
        mShaderMatrix.mapRect(mBorderRect);
        mBorderRect.inset((mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderWidth) / 2);
        mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBorderRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        break;

      case FIT_START:
        mBorderRect.set(mBitmapRect);
        mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.START);
        mShaderMatrix.mapRect(mBorderRect);
        mBorderRect.inset((mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderWidth) / 2);
        mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBorderRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        break;

      case FIT_XY:
        mBorderRect.set(mBounds);
        mBorderRect.inset((mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderWidth) / 2);
        mShaderMatrix.set(null);
        mShaderMatrix.setRectToRect(mBitmapRect, mBorderRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        break;
    }

    mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
    mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    super.onBoundsChange(bounds);

    mBounds.set(bounds);

    updateShaderMatrix();
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (mOval) {
      if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
        canvas.drawOval(mDrawableRect, mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawOval(mBorderRect, mBorderPaint);
      } else {
        canvas.drawOval(mDrawableRect, mBitmapPaint);
      }
    } else {
      if (mBorderWidth > 0) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mDrawableRect, Math.max(mCornerRadius, 0),
            Math.max(mCornerRadius, 0), mBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mBorderRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mBorderPaint);
      } else {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mDrawableRect, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, mBitmapPaint);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
  }

  @Override
  public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    mBitmapPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    invalidateSelf();
  }

  @Override
  public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    invalidateSelf();
  }

  @Override public void setDither(boolean dither) {
    mBitmapPaint.setDither(dither);
    invalidateSelf();
  }

  @Override public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
    mBitmapPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
    invalidateSelf();
  }

  @Override
  public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
    return mBitmapWidth;
  }

  @Override
  public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
    return mBitmapHeight;
  }

  public float getCornerRadius() {
    return mCornerRadius;
  }

  public RoundedDrawable setCornerRadius(float radius) {
    mCornerRadius = radius;
    return this;
  }

  public float getBorderWidth() {
    return mBorderWidth;
  }

  public RoundedDrawable setBorderWidth(int width) {
    mBorderWidth = width;
    mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);
    return this;
  }

  public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor.getDefaultColor();
  }

  public RoundedDrawable setBorderColor(int color) {
    return setBorderColors(ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
  }

  public ColorStateList getBorderColors() {
    return mBorderColor;
  }

  public RoundedDrawable setBorderColors(ColorStateList colors) {
    mBorderColor = colors != null ? colors : ColorStateList.valueOf(0);
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor.getColorForState(getState(), DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR));
    return this;
  }

  public boolean isOval() {
    return mOval;
  }

  public RoundedDrawable setOval(boolean oval) {
    mOval = oval;
    return this;
  }

  public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return mScaleType;
  }

  public RoundedDrawable setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    if (scaleType == null) {
      scaleType = ScaleType.FIT_XY;
    }
    if (mScaleType != scaleType) {
      mScaleType = scaleType;
      updateShaderMatrix();
    }
    return this;
  }

  public Bitmap toBitmap() {
    return drawableToBitmap(this);
  }
}
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RoundedImageView">
        <attr name="corner_radius" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="border_width" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="border_color" format="color" />
        <attr name="round_background" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="is_oval" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="android:scaleType" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="CircleLayout">
        <attr name="innerRadius" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="sliceDivider" format="reference|color" />
        <attr name="innerCircle" format="reference|color" />
        <attr name="angleOffset" format="float" />
        <attr name="angleRange" format="float" />
        <attr name="layoutMode">
            <enum name="normal" value="1" />
            <enum name="pie" value="2" />
        </attr>
        <attr name="dividerWidth" format="dimension" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**How To Use**

```
<YourPackageName.RoundedImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

Comment: under res->values directory.

Answer (score 0):

the following link might be useful here

http://murodese.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/rounded-imageviews-in-listviews/

Changing the width and height:

http://tech.pro/tutorial/620/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing